# ruby on rails use username or password not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I followed this [tutorial](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address).

But whenever I try to log in with my username and my password i keep getting the following error

**Invalid email or password.**

I guess since I followed the tutorial it would be working but its not.

Comment: What did you find if you run : rails console then try to find your user (User.find_by_email('my@email.com') ?

Comment: @fxuser: you don't have attr_protected: password ? ... if it was the case, Devise could not encrypt your password and you would get the "Invalid email or password" message ...

Comment: @citraL sorry, i am new to ruby so should i put this into the user model?

Comment: after adding it into my user model after the line `class User < ActiveRecord::Base` i still get the same error as above

Comment: ok it works i just had to do `bundle update` and `restart the dev server`

Comment: ok ... my message was that : if you use Devise, you should NOT have attr_protected: password. Glad to see it works !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok it works i just had to do bundle update and restart the dev server